# Clicking the top home button doesn't do anything

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbarsherlock. I have three screens as follows

1. lists items in list activity
2. lists items in list activity after an item from first screen is clicked
3. shows details about the clicked item.

On second screen I want to have home button that takes the user back to first scree, and on third screen I want to have a home button that takes the user back to second screen.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
//on second activity:
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("First");
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

//on third activity:
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Second");
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

This makes the button on top left show up but nothing happens when I click it.

I found online that this change needs to be made in `onOptionsItemSelected` as well. But I don't have `android.id.home` in my code. My IDE throws error on `android`....

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == /*what should I put here*/) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put here **android.R.id.home** - it is an Android home button id